# Cada vez que oprimo el boton el programa se cierra automaticamente

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.7, pyqt

Tengo un problema con mi programa, cada vez que lo corro y oprimo el botón de mi GUI el programa se cierra automaticamente. Cree una función que al momento de darle click al botón obtenga los datos de los lineEdit y obtenga el estado de los radioButtons, y a partir del radioButton seleccionado realice una operación.

Este es el codigo

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox
from PyQt5 import uic

#Clase Heredada de QMainWindow (Constructor de ventana)
class Ventana(QMainWindow):
      #Metodo constructor de la clase
      def __init__(self):
            #Iniciar el objeto QMainWindow
            QMainWindow.__init__(self)
            #Cargar la Configuracion del archivo ui en el objeto
            uic.loadUi("Bocinas.ui",self)
            self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Guardar)

      def closeEvent(self,event):
            resultado = QMessageBox.question(self,"Salir..","¿Seguro quiere salir?",QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
            if resultado == QMessageBox.Yes:
                  event.accept()
            else:
                  event.ignore()

      def Guardar(self):
            st = self.lineEdit.text()
            l = self.lineEdit_2.text()
            xo = self.lineEdit_3.text()
            m = self.lineEdit_4.text()
            M = self.lineEdit_5.text()
            sx=[]
            if self.radioButton.isChecked():
                  for i in range(l):
                        s=st*((i/xo)**2)
                        sx.append(s)
            elif self.radioButton_2.isChecked():
                  for i in range(l):
                        s=st*((i/xo)**2)
                        sx.append(s)
            elif self.radioButton_3.isChecked():
                  for i in range(l):
                        s=st*((i/xo)**2)
                        sx.append(s)
            elif self.radioButton_4.isChecked():
                  for i in range(l):
                        s=st*((i/xo)**2)
                        sx.append(s)
            else:
                  opcion = QMessageBox.Retry(self,"Seleccione algun tipo de Bocina")


#Instancia para iniciar una app
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
#Crear un objeto de la clase
_ventana = Ventana()
#Mostrar ventana
_ventana.show()
#Ejecutar app
app.exec_()
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Tengo un problema con mi programa, cada vez que lo corro y oprimo el botón de mi GUI el programa se cierra automaticamente. Cree una función que al momento de darle click al botón obtenga los datos de los lineEdit y obtenga el estado de los radioButtons, y a partir del radioButton seleccionado realice una operación.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'Bocinas.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.14.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 140, 191, 51))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 280, 311, 251))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 100, 273, 153))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.layoutWidget.setFont(font)
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(3, 1, 0, 10)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(4)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_5)
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 340, 171, 21))
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 370, 171, 21))
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        self.radioButton_3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 400, 171, 21))
        self.radioButton_3.setObjectName("radioButton_3")
        self.radioButton_4 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 430, 171, 21))
        self.radioButton_4.setObjectName("radioButton_4")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 100, 161, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 130, 161, 21))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 160, 161, 21))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 190, 161, 21))
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 220, 161, 21))
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuArchivo = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuArchivo.setObjectName("menuArchivo")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionAbrir = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionAbrir.setObjectName("actionAbrir")
        self.actionGuardar = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionGuardar.setObjectName("actionGuardar")
        self.menuArchivo.addAction(self.actionAbrir)
        self.menuArchivo.addAction(self.actionGuardar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuArchivo.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Graficar"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Área de garganta"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Longitud"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Distancia entre origen y garganta"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ensanchamiento"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Factor de forma"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Conica"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Catenoidal"))
        self.radioButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Hiperbolica"))
        self.radioButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exponencial"))
        self.menuArchivo.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Archivo"))
        self.actionAbrir.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Abrir"))
        self.actionGuardar.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Guardar"))
```

Aqui esta el codigo de Bocinas.py, extraido de Bocinas.ui

Comment: Hola Skinny C, ¿podrias agregar Bocinas.ui o si es muy extenso subirlo a Google Drive o similar para poder reproducir el problema)

Comment: Claro aqui esta el codigo de Bocinas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unas cuantas observaciones:

- [QMessageBox.Retry](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#StandardButton-enum) no es un "tipo de mensaje preconstruido", solo lo son `information()`, `question()`, `warning()` y `critical()`.
- Tus variables `st`, `l`, `xo`, `m` y `M` son cadenas (`str`) retornadas por `QLineEdit.text`. Estás intentando operar con ellas como si fueran numéricas (`int` o `float`). Debes convertirlas antes al tipo correspondiente o tendrás las esperadas excepciones. Supongo que `l` es `int` porque la usas en `range`, el resto voy a asumir que son `float`.
- Deberías validar los QLineEdit para evitar que el usuario ingrese algo que no sea un número, incluso que no sea un valor dentro del rango esperado. Para ello puedes usar [`QIntValidator`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qintvalidator.html) o [`QDoubleValidator`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublevalidator.html), etc según corresponda.

El código completo podría quedar:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox
from PyQt5 import uic
from Bocinas import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIntValidator, QDoubleValidator
from PyQt5.QtCore import QLocale

# Clase Heredada de QMainWindow (Constructor de ventana)
class Ventana(QMainWindow):
    #Metodo constructor de la clase
    def __init__(self):
        #Iniciar el objeto QMainWindow
        super().__init__()
        #Cargar la Configuracion del archivo ui en el objeto
        uic.loadUi("Bocinas.ui",self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.guardar)
        self._int_validator = QIntValidator()
        self._float_validator = QDoubleValidator()
        self.lineEdit.setValidator(self._float_validator)
        self.lineEdit_2.setValidator(self._int_validator)
        self.lineEdit_3.setValidator(self._float_validator)
        self.lineEdit_4.setValidator(self._float_validator)
        self.lineEdit_5.setValidator(self._float_validator)
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("0")
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText("0")
        self.lineEdit_3.setPlaceholderText("0")
        self.lineEdit_4.setPlaceholderText("0")
        self.lineEdit_5.setPlaceholderText("0")
        self._locale = QLocale() 

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        resultado = QMessageBox.question(
            self, "Salir..", "¿Seguro quiere salir?",
            QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No
            )
        if resultado == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def guardar(self):
        st, _ = self._locale.toDouble((self.lineEdit.text()))
        l, _ = self._locale.toInt(self.lineEdit_2.text())
        xo, _ = self._locale.toDouble(self.lineEdit_3.text())
        m, _ = self._locale.toDouble(self.lineEdit_4.text())
        M, _ = self._locale.toDouble(self.lineEdit_5.text())
        sx = []
        if self.radioButton.isChecked():
            for i in range(l):
                s = st * ((i / xo) ** 2)
                sx.append(s)
        elif self.radioButton_2.isChecked():
            for i in range(l):
                s = st * ((i / xo) ** 2)
                sx.append(s)
        elif self.radioButton_3.isChecked():
            for i in range(l):
                s = st * ((i / xo) ** 2)
                sx.append(s)
        elif self.radioButton_4.isChecked():
            for i in range(l):
                s = st * ((i / xo) ** 2)
                sx.append(s)
        else:
            QMessageBox.warning(
                self, 'Advertencia', "Seleccione algun tipo de Bocina",
                QMessageBox.Retry
                )


# Instancia para iniciar una app
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
# Crear un objeto de la clase
_ventana = Ventana()
# Mostrar ventana
_ventana.show()
# Ejecutar app
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Wow, muchas gracias man aprecio la ayuda brindada. Aún estoy aprendiendo PyQt5   y esto me ha ayudado a aprender mas de este lenguaje gracias de nuevo, buena noche.